# Should be a simple use of Ajax

Tags: html, ajax

Is there a reason the following html not output correctly?

```
<html>
<script src="jquery_v1.9.js" style="text/javascript" />
<script style="text/javascript"> $("#container").load('partial.html')</script>

<body>
<h1>Partial Rendering Demo</h1>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using an example in the ASP.net MVC 4 book, the jquery file is just a copy/paste from the most up-to-date version, all the files are in the same directory, and the 'partial.html' folder simple contains an h2 element. The h2 element however, is never displayed when I run the main html.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: `<script />` Are we having self-closing script tags these days?
Also see the answer below - your js is not dom ready

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script src="jquery_v1.9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function{
        $("#container").load('partial.html')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is there an ajax library maybe?

Comment: Just the h1 "Partial Rendering Demo" the partial has an h2 which just says "Ajax Partial" which is never displayed

Comment: by console I mean a browser console. See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)